# Launching external programs in C# without knowing the exact path

Tags: c#, .net, launch, process.start

I'm trying to create a C# program to launch other external applications.  I googled around and found this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start which I think is a pretty good tutorial.  The only problem I have is I don't always know the path for the programs.

For instance, if I do this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "firefox.exe";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

It launches firefox successfully.  However if I do this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "chrome.exe";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

It fails because it can't find chrome and it looks like I need to launch it from its exact path.  So my question is is there a way to access a universal registry of all installed applications and launch from there?  Thanks.

Comment: There isn't one. Not all programs "install" in the traditional sense. I would recommend investigating the programs you plan to launch to find their commom install locations.

Comment: You could always search the file system for "chrome.exe", once found save the path for later use.

Comment: @Magnus: And if there's more than one "chrome.exe"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applications can be directly launched when their folder path is in 'PATH' environment variable.

This variable can be viewed and edited in:

1. Right click 'Computer'
2. Properties.
3. *Advance Settings* if you're using 'Windows7' or 'Vista'
4. *Advance* tab
5. *Environment Variable*

Entries are separated by `;`.

I think you can lauch Firefox because Firefox already put its folder into PATH.

Comment: If he knew the path (to add the the environment variable) he would probably rather just add it to his program.

Comment: But the problem is some program or some installation doesn't registerd PATH. So he need to know it's hard to find an supposing program on harddisk.

Comment: I think Venatu and Magnus is right.  There is no universal registry from which to launch and so I should just search for the exe file.  Once I find it I'll just prompt the user to verify that that is indeed the correct path

Comment: If you don't mind lauching which kind of browser, you can just use the webpage's url like 'http://localhost:8888/bla.htm' as the __Filename__ of __startInfo__

Comment: I think there must be a way to achieve this. How does the built in command line program "start" know where to look? If you open a command line and write `start chrome` or `start firefox` chrome or firefox will start without me having to specify the path or add it to any environment variable... (at least on my computer)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I think I've found a solution.

Take a look at the registry keys below:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\

There is a key for each installed program. Chrome.exe for example.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx) method.
Can use it like this:

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")`

and it will return the string assigned to that variable.

Programs *usually* sign themselves inside that string in order to be able automatically located by Windows OS launching mechanism.

That means that in *this* case you may not know the **path** to executable, but **must know** the name of the program to launch.